Passing data between livewire components
I have 2 livewire components (using livewire 3) lets say comA and comB. In comA I store data idNumber into session
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
Session::put('id_number', $this->id_number);

but I can not retrieve this data in comB from session. But if I store same data in cache then I can retrieve it which I believe is not a good approach. is there any way I can pass data into comB. there is no child component here just 2 separate livewire components.
I have tried using events in livewire but wasn't successful. Might be because my comB load on the next page.

Events works only  for component present on the same page.  Try Session::put(......)->save()

The issue is solved by adding these classes to Kernel.php middleware array.
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
